# Is it possible to MERGE the OUTPUT of a DELETE query in SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two identically-shaped tables: an "active" table, and an "archive" table. As part of a recurring process, I want to *move* rows **from** the active **to** the archive, and I'd like to do it using `MERGE` so that my process doesn't fail with a `Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint '...'. Cannot insert duplicate key...`.

I had thought to do it like so:

```sql
MERGE INTO Archive
USING (DELETE FROM Active OUTPUT DELETED.* WHERE Active.Id IN (...)) AS Active
ON (Active.Id = Archive.Id)
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
INSERT (Id, ...)
VALUES (Active.Id, ...);
```

but then learned that `A nested INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE, or MERGE statement is not allowed in the USING clause of a MERGE statement.`

The only other thing that occurs to me is to use a temp table:

```sql
SELECT TOP 0 * INTO #temp FROM Active

DELETE FROM Active
OUTPUT DELETED.* INTO #temp
WHERE Id IN (...)

MERGE INTO Archive 
USING #temp AS Active
ON (Active.Id = Archive.Id)
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
INSERT (Id, ...)
VALUES (Active.Id, ...);
```

and it works, but it feels... unsatisfying.

Is there a more concise or direct way to achieve this "safe row movement"?

Comment: Since you don't have a WHEN MATCHED clause you could simply turn on IGNORE_DUP_KEY on the PK of Archive and INSERT instead of MERGE.

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft thank you for your suggestion, but wouldn't IGNOREing_DUP_KEY permit duplicate rows in the destination (Archive)? I do not want duplicates, that's why there's no WHEN MATCHED clause.

Comment: David, you don't mention what version of SQL you are using, however, if it's 2016+, have you looked into using SQL Server's temporal tables? It may be overkill for what you want, but it simplifies the process considerably. Here's a link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/tables/temporal-tables?view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: IGNORE_DUP_KEY will silently reject any duplicate rows on insert.  You do get a warning message, but not an error.  The behavior is similar to your MERGE statement. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/alter-table-index-option-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: Why "move" records, just set a field to flag record as "archived" then apply filter to exclude records.

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft Ah, I misunderstood those docs when I read them the first time. Thank you for the clarification.

Comment: @June7 because the active table contains ~220 million rows *after* removing the ~200 million that we want to archive. The data sizes and maintenance plans and so forth quickly become unwieldy if we just leave them.